# How to build a Textmate bundle from tmlanguage file?

Tags: textmate

How do I build a Textmate bundle from a `tmLanguage` file?

The `tmLanguage` file in question is [this one](https://github.com/dz4k/hyperscript-tmlanguage/blob/main/_hyperscript.tmLanguage).